# Using jQuery how should I style a DIV which is called by an Ajax method

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my page, few DIV elements are called dynamically through Ajax call and once they are loaded I want to style then using jQuery. What event should I use?

Comment: Post some code. If elements are being loaded via your ajax call, why not apply your styles at the end of the ajax callback?

Comment: Hey Thanks for idea. Basically I tried doing same thing.
I have added my jQuery code after the ajax callback done by developer in Java method. When I add a alert and then execute my code it works fine but when I remove alert then fails. Which means I am not able to run my code exactly after DIV is loaded completely. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Here is my sample code:
We are using SGWT technology and developer has written some Ajax call after which I am calling my jQuery method which is written in another Java file. Basically this Ajax call creates Body content on click of navigation link. When this body content is called I am trying to access Left Panel using my jQuery.
public void onClick(MenuItemClickEvent event) {
     contentWrapperLayout.setMembers(ipIterfacesPane);
     systemTabWrapper.setStyleName("menu_tab menu_default current");
                
     NativeScripts.changeBodyContent(); //Call of my jQuery Method here.

}

Comment: This is my jQuery Method:

 public static native void changeBodyContent() /*-{
            $wnd.$(".left_panel").livequery(function(){
                alert("Test");
                $wnd.$(".left_panel").removeAttr("style");
                $wnd.$(".left_panel div").removeAttr("style");
                $wnd.$(".left_panel table").removeAttr("style");
                $wnd.$(".left_panel table").removeAttr("width");
                $wnd.$(".left_panel table").removeAttr("height");
            });
     }-*/;

When I add alert it performs below script but when I remove alert then it fails... :(

Answer (score 0):

If you give them an ID when you create the DIV dynamically you can add a class with jquery.

```
$("#DivID").addClass("ClassName");
```

By using this you can create a class in your css to define the style and then add the style dynamically.

If you are printing out several.. give them a container class with an id and define a parent child relationship.

```
$("#Container > div").addClass("ClassName");
```

This will give the class to every div inside your containing div.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [livequery](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) plugin. Without some code, though, it's difficult to know what you want to do.

> Live Query utilizes the power of jQuery selectors by binding events or firing callbacks for matched elements auto-magically, even after the page has been loaded and the DOM updated.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the idea, I found same idea in another post on Stack Overflow but it didn't work for me. Do I need to add some plugin for this method?

Answer (score 0):

This example is one minor approach. You can use ajax start & stop events.

```
$('#yourdivid').ajaxStart(function() {
//Change your div style -- show   
$(this).css('display','block');

});

$('#yourdivid').ajaxStop(function() {
//Change your div style -- hide   
 $(this).css('display','none');  

});
```